# How to graphically represent a Probit regression after weighting using propensity scores in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, probit

So I have a Probit model that uses weights w, which I got from propensity scores, but I can't find any information on how to represent the Weighted Probit regression. All the information I could find was about normal probit regression...

Ideally I would like to get a classical probit representation, something like this graph:
[image]

Comment: Why do you want this graph? Is your treatment a continuous variable? Do you know how to create that plot with an unweighted probit regression? What have you tried? What software are you using?

Comment: I want to represent the same probit for different groups I have, men and women for example, to see the differences between both groups. My treatment is a dummy. I can create a plot like this using ggplot, but I have no idea how to integrate the weights inside the plot formula, and adding weights=w doesn't work... and I'm using R.

Comment: But what is the continuous variable in your analysis? Treatment is a binary variable; there is no curve. Please post the code you used to make the plot you posted and the code you have tried to use. You gave to provide detailed information if you want us to be able to help you.